# Как вставить responseXml из XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

В JS не сильна. Помогите вот этот скрипт:

```
$(document).on("click", "#somebutton", function() {             // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
    $.post("Servlet", function(responseXml) {                // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response XML...
        $("#somediv").html($(responseXml).find("data").html()); // Parse XML, find <data> element and append its HTML to HTML DOM element with ID "somediv".
    });
});
```

вставить сюда:

```
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
-----------  вот сюда --------------------
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", 'Servlet', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("val="+ val);
```

без (button и div) само собой. Принимаю с сервера list и дело в том, что на клиенте таблица будет в JSTL:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>
      <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
          <tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
              <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
              <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
      </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
```

сервер такой:

```
 String val = request.getParameter("val");
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(val);


        if (num > 0 && num <9 ){

            List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            Employee emp1 = new Employee();
            emp1.setId(1); emp1.setName("Pasha");emp1.setRole("Developer");
            Employee emp2 = new Employee();
            emp2.setId(2); emp2.setName("Masha");emp2.setRole("Manager");
            empList.add(emp1);empList.add(emp2);
            request.setAttribute("empList", empList);


            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Comment: Вика, вас устраивает мой ответ? Если нет, то напишите под ним что вам не понятно или не получается.

Comment: @Bharata, нет моего компа под рукой, отпишу. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен `xhr.responseText`, а не `xhr.responseXml`. Вставьте туда строку:

```
document.getElementById('demo').getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

Смотрите также ответы на английском SO:

- [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17604071/) (Parse XML через JavaScript)
- [Parse XML using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7228141/) (Parse XML через jQuery)

Comment: не выходит(, вставляла также document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;, но тоже ничего

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, куда надо вставить? В document.getElementById("demo")? И добавьте XML (ответ сервера).

Comment: Пытаюсь так: var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
                var value = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;   .....................    <div id="demo">
        <data>
            <table>
                  .....
            </table>
        </data>
    </div>

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, я попросил: И добавьте XML (ответ сервера).

Comment: как это сделать? сорри я в js совсем 0

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, ну вы же отдаёте клиенту XML (ответ сервера) по его запросу. Вот он мне и нужен, чтобы понять что читать. И ответ вы отдаёте через JSP. Или JSP (JavaServer Pages) тоже не знаете?

Comment: нет с JSP и java все норм)

Comment: ответ с сервера я указывала в топике, полностью класс doPost прописала. Отправляю список: request.setAttribute("empList", empList); jnghfdkz.

Comment: вся проблема в том, что бы первый мой пример поместить в XMLHttpRequest, так как в отдельности он работает норм и выводит список клиенту.

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, я не сразу понял, что вы отдаёте, т. к. с JSTL я не знаком. Заменил свой ответ - теперь должно работать.

Comment: сорри, по делам убегала, вернул список, но вместе с ним всю страницу целиком

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, пришлите как выглядит после вставки `document.getElementById('demo').getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText` элемент <div id="demo"></div>? Что там теперь внутри?

Comment: var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('demo1').getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

Comment: сделала как Вы и написали

Comment: <div id="demo1">
    <data>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Role1</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.empList}" var="emp">
        <tr><td><c:out value="${emp.id}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.name}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${emp.role}"></c:out></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </data>
</div>

Comment: в диве в таком виде

Comment: @VikaSmirnova, теперь со стороны JS всё правильно. Я так понимаю, что ошибка в JSP или в JSTL, т.к. JSTL не преобразован в HTML. Преобразуйте его и сразу отпишитесь тут, пожалуйста.

Comment: пробую как решу отпишу

Comment: вопрос исчерпан, моя ошибка в сервере напортачила, сразу не заметила.